# Calculate time difference in seconds in pandas if row in other column matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with 3 columns ('time', 'SEC', 'DeviceName') in a pandas DataFrame.  I'm using the following code to calculate the differences between rows in the 'time' column and assign to the 'SEC' column:

```
df['SEC'] = df['time'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
```

The 'DeviceName' column can have several different devices, so I need to modify this to only perform the calculation if the device name matches the previous row, otherwise assign a 0 to 'SEC'.

For example:

```
time                    SEC       DeviceName
4/18/2023 2:43:00                 Applied_AA-12
4/18/2023 3:13:00       1800      Applied_AA-12  # calculate because the device name matches the previous row
4/18/2023 3:35:53       0         Applied_AA-14  # don't calculate because the device name doesn't match the previous row
4/18/2023 3:36:03       10        Applied_AA-14  # calculate because the device name matches the previous row
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and show the *matching expected output* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupyBy.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.diff.html) :

```
df["SEC"] = df.groupby("DeviceName")["time"].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)

df.at[0, "SEC"] = np.nan # is this optional ?
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                 time     DeviceName     SEC
0 2023-04-18 02:43:00  Applied_AA-12     NaN
1 2023-04-18 03:13:00  Applied_AA-12 1800.00
2 2023-04-18 03:35:53  Applied_AA-14    0.00
3 2023-04-18 03:36:03  Applied_AA-14   10.00
```

Comment: I edited my question because I needed to add an extra element to the calculation.

Comment: You should instead open a new question (*as you often do*) because now your question is considered a moving target after the edit you made and my answer makes non sense to the reader.